# Во время обновления массива объектов mongoose удаляет все записи

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть модель события, в которой данные о е участниках частично денормализированы, и в массиве event.members хранятся не _id, а объекты

```
[
    {
        userId: 
        _userName:
        _userAvatarThumbsPath
        ....
    }, 
    { ... }, 
    { ... }
]
```

для обновления данных используется следующий код (предоставляю основную часть)

```
    ...
    async.parallel({

        user: function ( callback ) {
            user.update( { $pull: { joinedEvents: event._id } }, function ( err, affected ) {
                callback( err, user._id );
            });
        },

        event: function ( callback ) {

            event.update( { $pull: { members: { $elemMatch: { userId: user._id } } } }, function ( err, affected ) {
                callback( err, true );
            });
        }



       }, callback );
   ...
```

Если в user.joinedEvents хранятся обычные строки, то с удалением их проблем не возникает, и все работает адекватно.
А при использовании оператора $elemMatch при выходе одного участника, метод очищает весь массив event.members. То есть участники присоединяются, присоединяются, а потом один вышел и список участников пуст.

Использую 
NodeJS: 7.4.0
Mongoose: 4.6.8
Заранее благодарен за подсказки.

Comment: [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) это команда удаления. вам может быть [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) нужен

Comment: Возможно я не совсем ясно выразился. Мне нужно удалять тех конкретных участников, которые покинули сообщество. Вместо этого при выходе одного участника - удаляется не одна запись а все из массива event.members.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `{}` `event.update({}, { $pull: { members: { $elemMatch: { userId: user._id } } } }, function ` Может быть у вас и без  `$elemMatch` сработает, `event.update({}, { $pull: { members: { userId: user._id } } }, function `

Comment: Попробовал до того, как увидел Ваш комментарий, но все равно спасибо. Работает без $elemMatch

Answer (score 0):

```
event.update( { $pull: { members: { userId: user._id } } }, function ( err, affected ) {
   callback( err, true );
});
```